# How to stream live TS (transport stream) files on HTML player?

Tags: javascript, html, http-live-streaming, hls.js, transport-stream

I want to stream a transport stream file on a HTML player. Is there a way to implement it?

I have tried these following approaches to play the TS file-

a) Put it in a video tag:
I simply wrote a video tag 
But it showed me a blank screen.

b) I tried it with iframe tag:

I wrote  a simple  tag: 
It actually downloaded the file but screen turned blank.

c) I used HLS player for showing the ts file
The HLS (hls.js) validated the file. However it gave me the "manifestLoadError".

Can anyone helpe me with this HLS error?
Or suggest me another way to show this TS file?

Answer (score 1):

Browsers can not play ts. You need to convert to iso/fmp4 before playing.

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion. Actually i want to take live .TS file directly from a channel website & play it on my HTML player. Coverting it into iso/fmp4 will cause streaming delay

Comment: We'll that doesn't change teh fact that browsers can not play TS files. Period, no way to get around it. Assuming comparable codecs. converting from ts to mp4 would add an unnoticeable amount of delay (a few milliseconds at most)

Comment: Okay. Actually i am new to web development area. Could you also share how to convert ts to mp4?

Comment: It depends where you want to do the conversion. If its server side, just use ffmpeg. If you want to do it in the browser, You cal look at the hls.js source code for an example.

Answer (score 0):

you can use Format Factory is totally free to convert any video or audio formats to another..

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).